# My for loop isn't displaying a variable in another file

Tags: batch-file

So i want to call all files in a directory with a variable in it and later echo the variable. The only problem i'm having is it won't echo out the variable. It just says ECHO OFF.

Here's my current code.

```
// THIS IS MY FOR LOOP.
@echo off

:Message
for %%i in (Soemthing\*.bat) do (
    call %%i
    echo %Message%
)

pause
exit

// THIS IS THE FILE I WANT IT TO CALL.
@echo off

set %Message%=Some message here.
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). Your `set` command is wrong: `set "message=Some message here"`

Comment: No, doesn't work. Still says ECHO is off.

Comment: @Stephan It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
> type a.bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:Message
for %%i in (b.bat) do (
    call %%i
    echo !Message!
)
pause

> type b.bat
set "Message=Some message here."

> a.bat

Some message here.
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .

>
```

Comment: I don't want it to call b.bat, i want instead (*.bat) so it calls every file.

Comment: this is called an example. To show you how it works. Of course you can replace `b.bat` with `Soemthing\*.bat` and it would call every single bat file in that folder.